# How to load UI in background on Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a fragment that takes too long to load due to its OnCreateView() function configuring about 40 textboxes. Is there a way to put this in a background thread and display a progress indicator circle while it loads?

I have tried using AsyncTask, but when the OnCreateView() is called a second time, I get an error stating that I must use the original thread. Also the device is frozen and will not display any indicator while loading through AsyncTask.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do the operation about the UI in the other thread. The official document said:

> By design, Android View objects are not thread-safe. An app is expected to create, use, and destroy UI objects, all on the main thread. If you try to modify or even reference a UI object in a thread other than the main thread, the result can be exceptions, silent failures, crashes, and other undefined misbehavior.

So you should try to optimize the code about the fragment's `OnCreateView()` method instead of trying run it in the background thread. All the UI operation should be excuted in the main thread.

For more information, you can check the official document about the [etter performance through threading](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads).